# Creating promise in one thread and setting it in another

Tags: multithreading, c++11, promise, boost-thread

Can I have an `boost::promise<void>` created in a thread and set its value in another different thread through `boost::promise<void>::set_value()`.

I think I am having a crash because of this, probably, so I must guess that no, but I would need confirmation. Thanks in advance.

P.S.: Note that I am using boost implementation.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg promises are supposed to be thread safe, `set_value` behaves as if it's atomic.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum, `set_value` behaves atomically with respect to other calls to `set_value` (and `set_exception` and the `at_thread_exit` functions) but not atomically with respect to other members, such as `promise::swap` or the destructor. i.e. it is possible to call `set_value` in one thread, then invoke the promise's destructor in another thread before the `set_value` call has completed (and that would be undefined behaviour)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do that, but you must ensure that the call to `set_value()` does not conflict with anything in the other thread, such as the completion of the constructor or the start of the destructor.

(According to the C++ standard you cannot even make potentially concurrent calls to `set_value()` and `get_future()` but that is a [defect](http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-active.html#2412) and should get fixed.)

To give a more precise answer it would be necessary to see exactly what your code is doing.

Comment: Well, I am trying still some experiments at the time. Thanks for your help. The code is not particularly easy to follow. There are many callbacks executed from different threads through Job dispatchers. Will see if I can fix it myself. Thanks for this info, it is helpful.